# How to check the existence of the file in this file upload function?

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, file-upload

I am trying to develop upload file function with security as my programming instructor asked me to do. I implemented it in such a way that it will check the size, file format and the existence of the file. The logic was working well except for checking the existence of the file. For example, when I tried to upload a file which is already existed, I will not get a message telling me that the file is already existed and I don't know why it is not working.

```
protected void UploadFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(FileUpload1.HasFile)
            try 
            {
                string[] validTypes = { "bmp", "gif"};
                string ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);

                if (size < limit) 
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < validTypes.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (ext == "." + validTypes[i])
                        {
                            string path = @"~\Images\"; 
                            string comPath = Server.MapPath(path + "\\" + FileUpload1.FileName);
                            if (!File.Exists(comPath))
                            {
                                FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(comPath);
                                Label1.Text = "File uploaded";
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Label1.Text = "Existed";
                            }
                        }
                        else 
                        {
                            Label1.Text = "Invalid File." + string.Join(",", validTypes);
                        }
                    }                         
                }

                else 
                {
                    Label2.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                    Label2.Text = "file is heavy";
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Label2.Text = "The file could not be uploaded. The following error occured: " + ex.Message;
            }
}
```

When I debugged the code, I found that it will execute the else statement, but instead of displaying it to the user, it will display the message in the outer else statement which is "Invalid File.". **Why?**

```
if (ext == "." + validTypes[i])
                            {
                                string path = @"~\Images\"; 
                                string comPath = Server.MapPath(path + "\\" + FileUpload1.FileName);
                                if (!File.Exists(comPath))
                                {
                                    FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(comPath);
                                    Label1.Text = "File uploaded";
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    Label1.Text = "Existed";
                                }
                            }
                            else 
                            {
                                Label1.Text = "Invalid File." + string.Join(",", validTypes);
                            }
```

Also, my instructor told me that the following line causes a vulnerability called path traversal.

```
string path = @"~\Images\";
```

**So how to prevent this security hole? ?Any ideas?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is logical problem in you code.
In the block

```
for (int i = 0; i < validTypes.Length; i++)
```

It will always run two time for each file.

What you can do you take a Boolean variable at set it to false.

Go inside the loop and if file found set boolean to true and use break statement.
At the end of loop check for the Boolean value and code accordingly.

### Edit-1

Rather than looping through the array you can use like this

```
string[] stringArray = { "text1", "text2", "text3", "text4" };
string value = "text3";
int pos = Array.IndexOf(stringArray, value);
if (pos >- 1)
{
    // the array contains the string and the pos variable
    // will have its position in the array
}
```

### In your case

```
 string[] validTypes = { "bmp", "gif"};
 string ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
 int pos = Array.IndexOf(validTypes , ext );
 if(pos>=0)
 {
     string path = @"~\Images\"; 
     string comPath = Server.MapPath(path + "\\" + FileUpload1.FileName);
     if (!File.Exists(comPath))
     {
         FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(comPath);
         Label1.Text = "File uploaded";
     }
     else
     {
         Label1.Text = "Existed";
     }
 }
 else
 {
    Label1.Text = "Invalid File." + string.Join(",", validTypes);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Could you please elaborate more by giving me a sample code including the Boolean variable. I am confused about how to use it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I really appreciate it. It is working well now. What about the path traversal security hole mentioned in the question?

Comment: I don't think there is any such issue. It is when user get the information about your directories by some manipulation. Or by seeing the folder path in the url. Or Image url. etc. I don't have much Idea about this. Kindly put a new question for the same.https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Path_Traversal